# How to build erlang AMQP client in Mongooseim

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, mongoose-im

I am new in erlang. I am trying to build RabitMQ Erlang AMQP client library with my mongoose source so that I can use the library within my mongooseim modules. I downloaded the library source from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client.html). The .ez file contains two directories, ebin and includes. ebin contains .beam files and include contains erlang .hrl files. Will it work if I drop all the .hrl files into mongooseim's apps/ejabberd/include directory and all .beam files into ebin directory? I am using make and make rel for compiling mongooseim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its much easier and cleaner using Jon Brisbin's rebar friendly amqp library (https://github.com/jbrisbin). All I had do is to add rabbit_common and amqp_client repo in my dependency list from rebar.config file.

```
diff --git a/rebar.config b/rebar.config
index c719d98..cafdb0f 100644
--- a/rebar.config
+++ b/rebar.config
@@ -36,6 +36,8 @@
   {pa, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/lavrin/pa.git", "c616d3f9"}},
   {ecoveralls, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/nifoc/ecoveralls.git", "40fa0d2f2057fff29e964f94fccf6ef2f13d34d2"}},
   {mustache, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/mojombo/mustache.erl.git", "d0246fe143058b6404f66cf99fece3ff6e87b7ed"}},
+  {rabbit_common, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/jbrisbin/rabbit_common.git", "rabbitmq-3.5.0"}},
+  {amqp_client, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/jbrisbin/amqp_client.git", {tag, "rabbitmq-3.5.0"}}},
   {recon, "2.2.1", {git, "git://github.com/ferd/recon.git", {tag, "2.2.1"}}}
  ]}.
```

Then make and make rel. I can include amqp_client header from any mongooseim module using:

```
-include_lib("amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you suggest will work, but a cleaner approach is possible. You could tweak the Makefile to simply copy the library into the just built MongooseIM release directory, but there's a better way:

1. Download and unpack `amqp_client-3.5.1.ez` inside `mongooseim/apps/`.
2. Optionally check in `mongooseim/apps/amqp_client-3.5.1/` into your git repo, so you won't have to download it again each time you clone the repository.
3. Make `reltool` bundle the application just as it bundles MongooseIM dependencies and components, that is apply the following patch:

   ```
   diff --git a/rel/reltool.config.script b/rel/reltool.config.script
   index 731d58c..395a73f 100644
   --- a/rel/reltool.config.script
   +++ b/rel/reltool.config.script
   @@ -20,7 +20,9 @@ BaseAppsToRun = [compiler,
                     cowboy,
                     fusco,
                     folsom,
   -                 exometer],
   +                 exometer,
   +                 xmerl,
   +                 amqp_client],

    AppsToRunIn = BaseAppsToRun ++ proplists:get_value(apps_to_run, Conf, []),

   @@ -44,7 +46,9 @@ BaseAppsToInclude = AppsToRun ++
                         alarms,
                         idna,
                         recon,
   -                     setup
   +                     setup,
   +                     xmerl,
   +                     amqp_client
                         ],
   ```

   Please note that `xmerl` is a dependency of `amqp_client`, so also has to be added to the release.
4. `make rel` to rebuild the release with `amqp_client` bundled with MongooseIM.
5. Run the server (e.g. with `bin/mongooseimctl live` in `mongooseim/rel/mongooseim` directory) and verify that `amqp_client` is available and running:

   ```
   (mongooseim@localhost)1> application:which_applications().
   ... snipped ...
    {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.5.1"},
    {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.7"},
   ... snipped ...
   (mongooseim@localhost)2> amqp_client:start().             
   {error,{already_started,amqp_client}}
   ```

   (Don't mind the error, of course we want it to be started already.)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I followed your instructions and amqp_client is getting started. However, when I tried to include a header file and make mongooseim again I get errors: can't find include file "amqp_client.hrl". How to fix this ?